# rqna.net appears to mirror all SE content without credit

Tags: support

I can't remember where it is I'm supposed to report this, but since I frequent Superuser over most other SE sites, I figured I'd post it here:

http://www.rqna.net/ appears to mirror content from most SE sites without any credit.

http://www.rqna.net/index-isoh.html is their "Superuser" page.

As an example,

[Converting spaces (all) to tabs in UltraEdit not working?](https://superuser.com/questions/689414/converting-spaces-all-to-tabs-in-ultraedit-not-working) is copied here: http://www.rqna.net/qna/qwwnzp-converting-spaces-all-to-tabs-in-ultraedit-not-working.html

The profile links are in-site, and there is no mention of Stack Exchange copyright, in fact, they claim their own at the bottom.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: One of the Stack Exchange Community Managers confirmed that they're "very aware" of this particular site and are working on handling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

> Send all reports of SCRAPERs to us via the contact form linked at the
>   bottom of every page. Please include:
>
> - the URL of the copied post the URL of the original post on SE for high-rankers,
> - the search string you used (and the name of the search engine, if not Google)
> - any other details you noticed and want to share, because you're awesome